# Is there a way to order elements in an Association?

Tags: associations

```
assoc = Association[F67 -> {S51, S90}, F1 -> {S1, S43}, 
   F2 -> {S32, S51, S62, S65}, F3 -> {}, F4 -> {S8, S32, S51}, 
   F5 -> {S1, S43, S44}, F6 -> {S51, S55, S56}, 
   F7 -> {S45, S51, S55, S56}, F8 -> {S51, S55, S56}, 
   F9 -> {S1, S3, S6, S10, S32, S43, S55, S58, S73, S86}, 
   F11 -> {S51, S76}, F12 -> {S51, S76}, 
   F13 -> {S28, S51, S56, S71, S76, S95}, F14 -> {}, 
   F15 -> {S51, S98}, F16 -> {S39, S42, S43, S90}, F17 -> {}, 
   F18 -> {S50, S51, S67, S87}, F19 -> {S51}, F20 -> {S51}, 
   F21 -> {S44, S51, S74}, F22 -> {S1, S37, S43, S46, S100}, 
   F23 -> {S7, S10, S20, S21, S22, S23, S24, S25, S26, S30, S33, S51, 
     S52, S53, S63, S64, S68, S90, S91, S99}, 
   F24 -> {S51, S63, S88, S90}, 
   F25 -> {S51, S52, S62, S83, S84, S85, S88, S90, S97}, F66 -> {}, 
   F26 -> {S10, S27, S41, S51, S52, S57, S59, S62, S79, S83, S84, S85,
      S88, S90, S93, S94, S97}, 
   F27 -> {S5, S9, S10, S19, S27, S41, S44, S47, S51, S52, S57, S59, 
     S62, S79, S83, S84, S85, S88, S90, S93, S94, S97}, 
   F28 -> {S15, S18, S48, S49, S51, S54, S60, S62, S75, S83, S84, S90,
      S92, S97}, 
   F29 -> {S3, S6, S10, S14, S30, S34, S45, S47, S51, S52, S59, S62, 
     S63, S90}, F30 -> {S45, S51}, F31 -> {S40, S51, S61, S77, S78}, 
   F32 -> {S51}, F33 -> {S51, S57}, 
   F34 -> {S10, S11, S27, S47, S51, S52, S62, S63, S73, S81, S90, 
     S97}, F35 -> {S51}, F36 -> {S50, S51, S67}, 
   F37 -> {S1, S31, S37, S82}, F38 -> {S44, S51}, F39 -> {S51}, 
   F40 -> {S1, S37, S43}, F41 -> {S51}, F42 -> {S51}, 
   F43 -> {S16, S17, S51}, F44 -> {S16, S17, S51}, F45 -> {S44, S51}, 
   F46 -> {S51}, F47 -> {S44, S51}, F48 -> {S1, S37, S71, S100}, 
   F49 -> {S3, S6, S35, S38, S51, S66, S96}, 
   F50 -> {S3, S6, S13, S16, S17, S35, S38, S51, S66, S89, S96}, 
   F51 -> {S13, S16, S17, S27, S35, S38, S51, S80, S89, S96}, 
   F52 -> {S13, S27, S35, S38, S51, S80, S96}, 
   F53 -> {S4, S27, S35, S38, S44, S51, S80, S89, S96}, 
   F54 -> {S38, S51, S72, S80, S89, S96}, 
   F55 -> {S1, S12, S13, S36, S37}, F56 -> {S29, S35, S51, S66}, 
   F57 -> {S29, S35, S51, S66}, F58 -> {S29, S35, S44, S51, S66}, 
   F59 -> {S1, S37}, F60 -> {S2, S51, S70}, F61 -> {S2, S51, S70}, 
   F62 -> {S2, S51, S69, S70}, F63 -> {S43}, F64 -> {S51, S90}, 
   F65 -> {S51, S90}, F66 -> {}, F10 -> {S51, S56, S76}];
KeyTake[%, {F67, F63, F19, F10, F46}]
```

The output is
    <|F67 -> {S51, S90}, F63 -> {S43}, F19 -> {S51}, 
     F10 -> {S51, S56, S76}, F46 -> {S51}|>
Given this, can one extract a listing or table that orders all Fxx-> by the number of elements contained in the braces of each Fxx and shows the corresponding count of those elements? For example, F67 is associated with 2 elements {S51,S90}, F1 is associated with 2 elements {S1,S43}. I'd like to find all Fxx's that are associated with 0, 1, 2, 3, elements and have that finding ordered by the number of elements in the associated braces.

Comment: does `Sort@Map[Length]@assoc` give what you need?

Comment: That helps too but I would like to include the names of each elements in the list that Length operates on

Comment: PRG, you need to use @kglr to ensure that the user is notified of your response. Perhaps SortBy[] would do what you want?

Comment: @kglr thank you

Comment: @Michael E2 I using your idea I found that just Sort@assoc works too

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Query` and `Select`.

```
Query[Select[Between[{0, 3}]@Length@# &] /* SortBy[Length]]@assoc
```

> ```
> <|F14->{},F17->{},F3->{},F66->{},F19->{S51},F20->{S51},F32->{S51},F35->{S51},F39->{S51},F41->{S51},F42->{S51},F46->{S51},F63->{S43},F1->{S1,S43},F11->{S51,S76},F12->{S51,S76},F15->{S51,S98},F30->{S45,S51},F33->{S51,S57},F38->{S44,S51},F45->{S44,S51},F47->{S44,S51},F59->{S1,S37},F64->{S51,S90},F65->{S51,S90},F67->{S51,S90},F10->{S51,S56,S76},F21->{S44,S51,S74},F36->{S50,S51,S67},F4->{S8,S32,S51},F40->{S1,S37,S43},F43->{S16,S17,S51},F44->{S16,S17,S51},F5->{S1,S43,S44},F6->{S51,S55,S56},F60->{S2,S51,S70},F61->{S2,S51,S70},F8->{S51,S55,S56}|>
> ```

Adding sorting of the `Keys` requires a bit of extra work because they are alphanumeric symbols. Converting to strings gets the sort closer but has the issue that `"3" > "11"`. Converting the number strings to integers will get the sort correct.  Also a little ascending/descending operator *trickery* is needed.

```
Query[Select[Between[{0, 3}]@Length@# &] /* GroupBy[Length] /* 
   KeySort /* (Values@# &) /* Merge[Flatten], 
  KeySortBy[FromDigits@*Curry[StringDrop][1]@*SymbolName]]@assoc
```

> ```
> <|F3->{},F14->{},F17->{},F66->{},F19->{S51},F20->{S51},F32->{S51},F35->{S51},F39->{S51},F41->{S51},F42->{S51},F46->{S51},F63->{S43},F1->{S1,S43},F11->{S51,S76},F12->{S51,S76},F15->{S51,S98},F30->{S45,S51},F33->{S51,S57},F38->{S44,S51},F45->{S44,S51},F47->{S44,S51},F59->{S1,S37},F64->{S51,S90},F65->{S51,S90},F67->{S51,S90},F4->{S8,S32,S51},F5->{S1,S43,S44},F6->{S51,S55,S56},F8->{S51,S55,S56},F10->{S51,S56,S76},F21->{S44,S51,S74},F36->{S50,S51,S67},F40->{S1,S37,S43},F43->{S16,S17,S51},F44->{S16,S17,S51},F60->{S2,S51,S70},F61->{S2,S51,S70}|>
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks, yes that is very nice ... can I use Ordering in some way to have the Fxx ordered like F3->{},F14->{},F17->{}, etc?

Comment: @PRG Are your `Keys` strings or symbols. You have them here as symbols but I think that may be the result of your paste.  Similarly, are your `Values` list of strings or symbols. If they are not symbols please update the question with the correct types.

Comment: My keys are indeed symbols, e.g., F8, F36, etc are names of vertices in a graph; the same with values.

Comment: @PRG See update.

Comment: the Curry command doesnt work error is: "The expression Curry[StringDrop][1][F67] is not a list of digits or a string of valid digits"

Answer (score 1):

```
Map[{Length @ #, ## & @@ #} &] @ SortBy[assoc, Length]
```

> <|F14 -> {0}, F17 -> {0}, F3 -> {0}, F66 -> {0},
>   F19 -> {1, S51}, 
>    F20 -> {1, S51}, F32 -> {1, S51}, F35 -> {1, S51}, F39 -> {1, S51}, 
>    F41 -> {1, S51}, F42 -> {1, S51}, F46 -> {1, S51}, F63 -> {1, S43},
>      F1 -> {2, S1, S43}, F11 -> {2, S51, S76}, F12 -> {2, S51, S76}, 
>    F15 -> {2, S51, S98}, F30 -> {2, S45, S51}, F33 -> {2, S51, S57}, 
>    F38 -> {2, S44, S51}, F45 -> {2, S44, S51}, F47 -> {2, S44, S51}, 
>    F59 -> {2, S1, S37}, F64 -> {2, S51, S90}, F65 -> {2, S51, S90}, 
>    F67 -> {2, S51, S90},
>   F10 -> {3, S51, S56, S76}, 
>    F21 -> {3, S44, S51, S74}, F36 -> {3, S50, S51, S67}, 
>    F4 -> {3, S8, S32, S51}, F40 -> {3, S1, S37, S43}, 
>    F43 -> {3, S16, S17, S51}, F44 -> {3, S16, S17, S51}, 
>    F5 -> {3, S1, S43, S44}, F6 -> {3, S51, S55, S56}, 
>    F60 -> {3, S2, S51, S70}, F61 -> {3, S2, S51, S70}, 
>    F8 -> {3, S51, S55, S56},
>    F16 -> {4, S39, S42, S43, S90}, 
>    F18 -> {4, S50, S51, S67, S87}, F2 -> {4, S32, S51, S62, S65}, 
>    F24 -> {4, S51, S63, S88, S90}, F37 -> {4, S1, S31, S37, S82}, 
>    F48 -> {4, S1, S37, S71, S100}, F56 -> {4, S29, S35, S51, S66}, 
>    F57 -> {4, S29, S35, S51, S66}, F62 -> {4, S2, S51, S69, S70}, 
>    F7 -> {4, S45, S51, S55, S56},
>   F22 -> {5, S1, S37, S43, S46, S100}, 
>    F31 -> {5, S40, S51, S61, S77, S78}, 
>    F55 -> {5, S1, S12, S13, S36, S37}, 
>    F58 -> {5, S29, S35, S44, S51, S66},
>   F13 -> {6, S28, S51, S56, S71, S76, S95}, 
>    F54 -> {6, S38, S51, S72, S80, S89, S96},
>   F49 -> {7, S3, S6, S35, S38, S51, S66, S96}, 
>    F52 -> {7, S13, S27, S35, S38, S51, S80, S96},
>   F25 -> {9, S51, S52, S62, S83, S84, S85, S88, S90, S97}, 
>    F53 -> {9, S4, S27, S35, S38, S44, S51, S80, S89, S96},
>   F51 -> {10, S13, S16, S17, S27, S35, S38, S51, S80, S89, S96}, 
>    F9 -> {10, S1, S3, S6, S10, S32, S43, S55, S58, S73, S86},
>   F50 -> {11, S3, S6, S13, S16, S17, S35, S38, S51, S66, S89, S96},
>   F34 -> {12, S10, S11, S27, S47, S51, S52, S62, S63, S73, S81, S90, 
>      S97},
>   F28 -> {14, S15, S18, S48, S49, S51, S54, S60, S62, S75, S83,
>       S84, S90, S92, S97}, 
>    F29 -> {14, S3, S6, S10, S14, S30, S34, S45, S47, S51, S52, S59, S62,
>       S63, S90},
>   F26 -> {17, S10, S27, S41, S51, S52, S57, S59, S62, S79, S83, S84, 
>      S85, S88, S90, S93, S94, S97},
>   F23 -> {20, S7, S10, S20, S21, S22, S23, S24, S25, S26, S30, S33, 
>      S51, S52, S53, S63, S64, S68, S90, S91, S99},
>   F27 -> {22, S5, S9, S10, S19, S27, S41, S44, S47, S51, S52, S57, S59,
>       S62, S79, S83, S84, S85, S88, S90, S93, S94, S97}|>

Comment: very nice and compact!! ... thank you!

Comment: @PRG, my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Sort@Map[Length]@assoc
y = Sort@assoc
Merge[{x, y}, Flatten]
```

This works well and produces

```
<|F3 -> {0}, F14 -> {0}, F17 -> {0}, F66 -> {0}, F19 -> {1, S51}, 
 F20 -> {1, S51}, F32 -> {1, S51}, F35 -> {1, S51}, F39 -> {1, S51}, 
 F41 -> {1, S51}, F42 -> {1, S51}, F46 -> {1, S51}, F63 -> {1, S43}, 
 F67 -> {2, S51, S90}, F1 -> {2, S1, S43}, F11 -> {2, S51, S76}, 
 F12 -> {2, S51, S76}, F15 -> {2, S51, S98}, F30 -> {2, S45, S51}, 
 F33 -> {2, S51, S57}, F38 -> {2, S44, S51}, F45 -> {2, S44, S51}, 
 F47 -> {2, S44, S51}, F59 -> {2, S1, S37}, F64 -> {2, S51, S90}, 
 F65 -> {2, S51, S90}, F4 -> {3, S8, S32, S51}, 
 F5 -> {3, S1, S43, S44}, F6 -> {3, S51, S55, S56}, 
 F8 -> {3, S51, S55, S56}, F21 -> {3, S44, S51, S74}, 
 F36 -> {3, S50, S51, S67}, F40 -> {3, S1, S37, S43}, 
 F43 -> {3, S16, S17, S51}, F44 -> {3, S16, S17, S51}, 
 F60 -> {3, S2, S51, S70}, F61 -> {3, S2, S51, S70}, 
 F10 -> {3, S51, S56, S76}, F2 -> {4, S32, S51, S62, S65}, 
 F7 -> {4, S45, S51, S55, S56}, F16 -> {4, S39, S42, S43, S90}, 
 F18 -> {4, S50, S51, S67, S87}, F24 -> {4, S51, S63, S88, S90}, 
 F37 -> {4, S1, S31, S37, S82}, F48 -> {4, S1, S37, S71, S100}, 
 F56 -> {4, S29, S35, S51, S66}, F57 -> {4, S29, S35, S51, S66}, 
 F62 -> {4, S2, S51, S69, S70}, F22 -> {5, S1, S37, S43, S46, S100}, 
 F31 -> {5, S40, S51, S61, S77, S78}, 
 F55 -> {5, S1, S12, S13, S36, S37}, 
 F58 -> {5, S29, S35, S44, S51, S66}, 
 F13 -> {6, S28, S51, S56, S71, S76, S95}, 
 F54 -> {6, S38, S51, S72, S80, S89, S96}, 
 F49 -> {7, S3, S6, S35, S38, S51, S66, S96}, 
 F52 -> {7, S13, S27, S35, S38, S51, S80, S96}, 
 F25 -> {9, S51, S52, S62, S83, S84, S85, S88, S90, S97}, 
 F53 -> {9, S4, S27, S35, S38, S44, S51, S80, S89, S96}, 
 F9 -> {10, S1, S3, S6, S10, S32, S43, S55, S58, S73, S86}, 
 F51 -> {10, S13, S16, S17, S27, S35, S38, S51, S80, S89, S96}, 
 F50 -> {11, S3, S6, S13, S16, S17, S35, S38, S51, S66, S89, S96}, 
 F34 -> {12, S10, S11, S27, S47, S51, S52, S62, S63, S73, S81, S90, 
   S97}, F28 -> {14, S15, S18, S48, S49, S51, S54, S60, S62, S75, S83,
    S84, S90, S92, S97}, 
 F29 -> {14, S3, S6, S10, S14, S30, S34, S45, S47, S51, S52, S59, S62,
    S63, S90}, 
 F26 -> {17, S10, S27, S41, S51, S52, S57, S59, S62, S79, S83, S84, 
   S85, S88, S90, S93, S94, S97}, 
 F23 -> {20, S7, S10, S20, S21, S22, S23, S24, S25, S26, S30, S33, 
   S51, S52, S53, S63, S64, S68, S90, S91, S99}, 
 F27 -> {22, S5, S9, S10, S19, S27, S41, S44, S47, S51, S52, S57, S59,
    S62, S79, S83, S84, S85, S88, S90, S93, S94, S97}|>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Sort@Map[Length]@assoc
y = Sort@assoc
Merge[{x, y}, Flatten]
```